# Do we need to create or configure dimension attribute relationship even if we don't have dimension hierarchy in it?

Tags: ssas

I'm new to SSAS OLAP.

I have a dimension and it has no hierarchies in it.

So at this dimension, do we need to configure attribute relationship for that. Because I'm getting unexpected calculation results while doing like this.

If we need to configure attribute relationship then please provide information that why it is to be configured.

Can anyone help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe, hard to say without knowing all the details of your dimension.

Comment: @TabAlleman Can you please have a look into the following link, at which I have posted my question in a detailed manner. Please let me know do I need to provide any further details. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86960/which-is-the-best-way-for-selecting-dimension-attributes-while-creating-a-dimens

Comment: Your deposit log table isn't a dimension table, it's a fact table.  It should be used to create a Measure Group in your SSAS cube, not a dimension.